# javascript regular expressions phone number

Tags: phone-number

I have written a regular expression for phone number for different countries. But, I din't resolve problem: when user enters phone number +345)-234355464 (with one bracket for country code) this phone number is valid. This is incorrect behavior. It should be two brackets or none. Please, advise me how to resolve this problem? below is my regular expression.

```html
/^(\+?((\(?\d{2}\)?[-.\s]?(\d{4}))|(\(?\d{3}\)?[-.\s]?)))([0-9\s-]{1,14})$/
```

Comment: can you specify exactly what would a "correct" input look like . like this :  +(345)-234355464 ?

Comment: correct phone number can be  can be consist  from 10 to 20 characters, with or + without + first, with brackets or without brackets for entering the country code. The problem I have only occurs with brackets to enter the country code, but in General the expression is correct,except for the brackets